# Converting all NSData in a large NSDictionary to Hex-NSString in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdata

I have multiple large dynamically created `NSDictionaries` which contain (among other) multiple `NSData` objects.

I need to "pretty-print" this dictionary. Using `-description` I get a quite good result except for the `NSData` stuff which is not completely printed as it is cropped by the method.

Is there a way (except for iterating over the whole dictionary with a nested for-loop) to convert all the `NSData` objects to a Hex-String representation?

Comment: How would you expect to convert all data not iterating its content?

Comment: What I mean was "not manually iterating over its content"